# Separate aluminium from brass threaded bushing without affecting the brass

Tags: metal, metallurgy, alloy

I wanted to separate aluminium from brass threaded bushing without affecting the brass.

I also suppose that brass isn't the brass but it's a phosphor bronze.

Does brass and phosphor bronze amalgamate with mercury without scratching?

Is it possible to dissolve aluminium without affecting the brass?

I've also read that aluminium can corrode in the presence of brass, but I suppose brass is isolated from bushing or pressed really tight to prevent corrosion.

Comment: As brass contains zinc, it would probably get corroded, because aluminium and zinc have similar dissolution behaviour.

Comment: Try NaOH. Hot NaOH is needed for Zinc but aluminium is good with room temperature NaOH

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Aluminum in contact with any copper alloy will be anodic and corrode rapidly if any conductive liquid is present ( eg. water).

Comment: So hydrogen peroxide would be the best option? Corroding aluminium would not damage copper alloy?

Comment: @MalumWolfram, where did you the idea to use H2O2? The comments do not suggest it.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I've read that $H_{2}O_{2}$ accelerates corrosion.